# How to call/include an ip address from inventory file to ansible playbook

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ansible, redhat

```
---

- hosts: pupservers
  sudo: yes

  tasks:
  - command: bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 2  --partitions 1 --topic my-replicated-topic
    with_inventory_hostnames: zookservers
```

In the above code I need call an ip address of another variable declared as zookservers in inventory file instead of local host.

I tried different things but nothing worked for me , tried to call `{{ ansible_ssh_host }}`, `{{ zookservers[ansible_ssh_host] }}`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, your play is limited to the group `pupservers`. Ansible will only know facts about hosts it is supposed to run something on. `zookservers` is a different group not involved in your play, so Ansible will not connect to these hosts and not collect facts (including the ip)

To make Ansible gather facts on the hosts of the group `zookservers` you can simply add an empty play to your playbook. So your playbook would look like this:

```
- hosts: zookservers

- hosts: pupservers
  sudo: yes

  tasks:
  - ...
```

<sub>[Fact caching](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#fact-caching) would be another option but I guess this should suit your needs.</sub>

In your loop then you should be able to get the IP with

```
{{ hostvars[item].ansible_eth0.ipv4.address }}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{{ hostvars['zookservers']['ansible_eth0']['ipv4']['address'] }}
```

Comment: helloV, the above answer is not working. actually I zookservers is another group from pupservers. but both are in default inventory file.my question is how to call and ip address from inventory file to a playbook where it is not included in hosts

Comment: How do you invoke your playbook? Can you paste your command here? Do you use `-i` option to specify the inventory file path?

Comment: ansible-playbook kafkatest.yaml

Comment: zook ansible_ssh_host=172.30.0.243
kaf1 ansible_ssh_host=172.30.0.212
kaf2 ansible_ssh_host=172.30.0.73
pup ansible_ssh_host=172.30.0.251

[kafkaservers]
kaf1
kaf2

[zookservers]
zook

[pupservers]
pup

[testservers:children]
kafkaservers
zookservers